# Can the STK500 program an XMEGA?

Tags: xmega, avr

Can the STK500 program the XMEGA as it arrives from Atmel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the device support for the STK500 in the AVR Studio Help you will see that the XMega isn't supported, you need an STK600. I'd use a Dragon, it's a lot cheaper and gives debugging as well as programming.

Comment: It's only cheaper if you don't already have an STK500 :-) Will probably pick up a Dragon though. Thanks.

Comment: I've got an STK500 and a Dragon. 8-)

Comment: Also, I think you need a "daughter board" for the STK600 that has a ZIF socket and appropriate routings for your particular flavor of XMEGA.

Comment: There are ZIF sockets for TQFP and QFN parts?